# Creating a cloud front distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I followed Ryan Kroonenburg's tutorial to create a cloud front distribution. I set the source to one of the S3 buckets that I had created.I set "Restrict Bucket Access" to yes when I created the cloud front. I am still able to access to the S3 bucket though the info next to this option states "If you want to require that users always access your Amazon S3 content using CloudFront URLs, not Amazon S3 URLs, click Yes. ". When I try to access the cloud front url , I see the below.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>56299E51ECB22FF0</RequestId>
<HostId>
sv5htrLwzMPiwZWyu4nUh6+Z8ZM69rC/fxNiC5zLR5rms9X+cRnoSeHJnElx7A7s9dCr36lRmU4=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: It seems like its a permission error. Can you cross check with the following guide to setup CloudFront Origin Access Identity to serve private content http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To configure serving private S3 content through AWS CloudFront, multiple configurations are required, both at S3 and CloudFront.

- Create a CloudFront origin access identity(Special CloudFront user) granting access to S3 bucket. This will also create a user in S3 ACL allowing access.
- Restrict S3 bucket access by public (Configuring S3 ACL permissions removing anonymous access)

The information message to click YES in CloudFront is to create a origin access identity from CloudFront to access the content from S3(Regardless of the bucket being private or public).

> If you want to require that users always access your Amazon S3 content
>   using CloudFront URLs, not Amazon S3 URLs, click Yes.

To make the bucket private, make sure you control the access through S3 buckets ACL permissions tab and you will also see a new type of user granted to access the S3 (Origin Access Identity User) which is for CloudFront.

Since you are receiving an access error, I would recommend to go through either the documentation or articles to find the route cause and also to understand how it works underneath so that you can troubleshoot future issues.

- AWS Developers Guide: [Using an Origin Access Identity to Restrict Access to Your Amazon S3 Content](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)
- AWS Security Blog: [How to Restrict Amazon S3 Bucket Access to a Specific IAM Role](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/)

Comment: Thanks Ashan for the detailed response. Now I am just trying to access the picture that I have uploaded to S3 bucket using cloud front. I gave full read / write permissions to my s3 bucket and I am able to access the picture using S3 bucket url. When I set up the distribution ,I am setting "Grant Read Permissions on Bucket" to yes. However each time I edit Origin Settings , this shows up as "No , I will update the permissions". So I am unable to figure out if the value is already set to yes. Even now I am unable to access the picture using cloud front endpoint.

Comment: @PunterVicky examine the bucket policy to see if there is a statement related to the origin access identity.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed blog on creating S3 bucket with restricted access.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/